# Nearest neighbor classifier on a simple dataset

Tags: machine-learning, data-analysis, logistic-regression

Consider the following data set for two classes $X_1 = \{ (0,0) \}, X_2 = \{(1,0),(0,1)\}$

I'm trying to come up with a rule to separate the data using k-nn for $k = 1$. But I don't know how to apply the k-nn algorithm on this data set. Can anyone help?

Comment: Compute the Euclidean distance between the points and cluster the points on a two-by-two basis based on the points having minimum distance between each other.

Comment: This question was taken from a book, and in the book the solution is: $y(x) =  1 \,$ if $\, x_i <0.5$ and $y(x) = 2 \,$ if $\, x_i > 0.5 $. How does one arrive at that conclusion from the k-nn algorithm?